# Minimal perfect hash function for set of integers

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashing

This might be a trivial question, but I have the following problem: I want to (perfectly) hash a number of lists of integers of length $n$, with all entries between $k_{min}$ and $k_{max}$. How can I construct a perfect hash function $h$ that takes such a list and outputs an $m$-bit number where $m$ is as small as possible? This is of course trivial if $k_{max} - k_{min} + 1$ is a power of two, e.g. if $n = 3$, $k_{max} = 15$ and $k_{min} = 0$, we can choose $m = 4$ and $h$ such that:

$$
\begin{align}
h([0, 0, 0]) &= \mathtt{0x000000} \\
h([0, 0, 1]) &= \mathtt{0x000001} \\
&\dots \\
h([15, 15, 15]) &= \mathtt{0xffffff}
\end{align}
$$

But what if $k_{max} - k_{min} + 1$ is not a power of two and I don't want to "round" up the number of bits used to represent every element because I want to save every single last bit of space?

Comment: Multiply the $i$-th list element by $(k_{max}-k_{min}+1)^i$.

Comment: To elaborate on the above comment, let $N = (k_{max} - k_{min} + 1)$, and treat the list as a number in base-$N$. For example, say the entries are in $\{3, 4, 5, 6\}$. Then $N = $, and treat the list $[3, 4, 4, 3, 6]$ as the string of digits $01103$, then treat that string of digits as a number in base 4 by mapping it to $3 + 4 \times 0 + 4^2 \times 1 + 4^3 \times 1 + 4^4 \times 0$.

Comment: @Joppy: Okay, I think I got it, that does seem pretty simple after all.

Comment: @j_random_hacker (and Joppy) Please don't write answers as comments. This question is now answered but will never get marked as such, and you're missing out on free reputation.

Comment: @Joppy is there a way to generate a hash as you add new numbers to the list some how? If you know the hash for {3,4,5,6} and then add say 17 so you now how {3,4,5,6,17} would you have to iterate the whole list to get a new hash or is there a simple way to update the hash ?